# Type of brakes that will work with beach cruiser with no brake hole in wheel

Tags: brakes, cruiser

My daughter has a 24" beach cruiser and doesn't like pedalling backwards to stop. She really wants hand brakes. There is a hole in the frame above the tire (where a rear light might be installed) but no brake hole in the wheel itself. Is there a braking system that can be installed that doesn't require a hole? My husband said that the brake hole was needed. I don't know that much about braking systems.

Comment: What do you mean "Brake hole in the wheel"? The hole in the frame you describe sounds like you could mount rim brakes on it. Special holes in the wheel sounds like it would be required to mount a disc for disc brakes.

Comment: See [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/81822#81822) for a description of rim brakes, and [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/4425#4425) for disc brakes.

Comment: I'd guess that caliper brakes are made that would work for a front and/or rear brake. It's hard to say for sure without seeing it. A picture of the bike looking from the rear of the bike towards the seat and another picture of the bike from the front looking towards the front so that we can see the back of the frame and the front of the fork would help us give a good answer.

Comment: Pictures please, ideally: that region where you've got a possibly-helpful hole, the top of the (front) fork, the hub (middle) of each wheel from the left of the bike including the nearby frame/fork

Comment: I wonder if OP is mixing features of caliper and V brakes together?  Or  possibly thinking about disk rotor mounts in the hub of a wheel ?

Comment: It would be very helpful to see a photo of the frame and the wheel. Sounds like it should be possible, as long as there is a hole for the brakes in the frame.